# How to implement deep and shallow copy constructors without using a boolean parameter?

Tags: c++

I have the following class:

```
class A {
    int small;
    std::shared_ptr<B> big;
};
```

Here, `B` is a class whose objects are expected to have a very large size.
In my program, I have an original object of class `A` and then make multiple copies of it, then copies of the copies, etc.

Sometimes, I need to make a deep copy, because all members might be modified. Other times, I know that I won't make any changes to `A::big` and thus I would like to copy only the pointer in order to save resources (a profiler showed me that this is a bottleneck).

Currently, I have the following:

```
A(const A& other, bool doDeepCopy): 
    small{other.small}, big{doDeepCopy ? std::make_shared<B>(*other.big) : other.big} {}
```

I am aware that using `bool` parameters [is considered bad style](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/147977/is-it-wrong-to-use-a-boolean-parameter-to-determine-behavior), but I don't know what else to do. The default copy constructor makes a shallow copy, and I could encapsulate it within a function `A A::makeShallowCopy()`. But how should the other constructor look like? The only input it needs is an object of type `A`, but I obviously cannot have two functions with the same signature.

Comment: I'd be tempted to make a clone method for the deep copies and leave the copy constructor to do shallow copies... I am assuming the bool you though about using would be explicitly provided, so the calling code could call copy or clone as appropriate?

Comment: But the clone method also needs to call some sort of copy constructor, doesn't it? Or would you have it call the defualt copy constructor and then overwrite the pointer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming B has a copy constructor, just add:

```
class A {
    int small;
    std::shared_ptr<B> big;

public:
    A clone() const {
        return { small, std::make_shared<B>(*big) };
    }
};
```

So `clone()` becomes the only way to deep-copy your data.

---

That's the method used in OpenCV and Eigen for matrices: the copy is shallow by default, and an explicit call to `replicate()` or `clone()` is required for deep copies.

Comment: This assumes that we have a constructor `A(int s, std::shared_ptr<B> b)`. If it doesn't already exist (for example because the main constructor `A(int s)` only saves the value `s` in `small` and generates `big` using a random-number generator), is it acceptable to introduce a new constructor that doesn't look like a copy constructor but is one in practice?

Comment: You could have a public `A(int s)` delegating to a protected `A(int s, std::shared_ptr<B> b)`. `A(int s)` would inject the randomly-generated object as 2nd parameter, and `clone()` would pass `std::make_shared<B>(*big)` instead.